# How to add a class to the body element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

So I wanted to code a simple thing in javascript, I have a responsive navbar with the hamburger button:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="validate()">
<label for="check" class="checkbtn">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</label>
```

I wanted to halt scrolling whenever the hamburger menu is active. So I wrote this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    var element = document.getElementByTagName("body")[0];
    if (document.getElementById('check').checked){
        element.classList.add("noscroll");
    }
}
```

And of course I added `.noscroll{ overflow: hidden; }` to the css file.

It didn't work for some reason which I hope you guys will help me identify.

Comment: Is the class added to the body?

Comment: No it is not added.

Comment: When you are debugging code you should always have your developer console open so you can look for errors thrown by the brower. In this case, your code is probably throwing `document.getElementByTagName is not a function`, since the function is `getElementsByTagName`. I would suggest searching the web for "javascript debugging" to add to your skill set.

Comment: As mentioned, *getElementByTagName* doesn't exist. An easier way to access the body is `document.body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest answer, hope it helps

```
const body = document.body;
body.classList.add("MyClass");
```

Comment: Wouldn't `document.body.classList.add('MyClass')` be shorter?

Comment: yep, but I was in functional approach mid-set,  same result btw and yours is shorter